# Load struts tag in js file or pass values from action to js file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts

I was searching for a way to use struts tag in .js files so that i can directly pass a value from action class to .js file when js is loaded into the page (of course, it can be done if the script is inside `<script>` tag inside a jsp file. But i want to directly pass to js file.). I found a solution in  [this link](http://xplore-java.blogspot.in/2009/09/how-to-use-struts-tags-in-java-script.html) which asks to add `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>` at the top of the js file and add the following in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name >JspServlet</servlet-name >
    < servlet-class >org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class >


<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>JspServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/scripts/dynamic/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(sorry to add the xml code as a html snippet. Didn't find any other way to do it).
But it didn't work for me. Can some one help me with a way to do it..?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually what u need is values from the action class.right?  may be u can use the  to a hidden type then use the id of the hidden type to get the value. You may try.like...

```
<input type="hidden" value="<s:property value='your variable'/>" id="my_id"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Zionz. Of course thats a clever way of doing it. But Isn't there any method to pass values to js file from class.

Comment: Have u tried to pass the value directly to js variable? Like,   var name='<s:property value="%{varible}"/>';

Comment: it's working for me mate...can u please put your code here?